# How to loop through folders if I do not necessarily know their structure but only the destination?

Tags: c#, search, recursion, directory

I'm writing a program that needs to access a file inside of `c:\program files\program_name\`.

My target file will always be inside of `\program_name\program_name\bin\something.exe`

However, because the program is extracted from an archive, if the user unpacks it improperly, it'll be simply `\program_name\bin\something.exe`, skipping a whole level.

Currently I'm basically getting the contents of `c:\program files\`, collecting the names of all folders that contain `program_name`, then adding them to the list and then using the list to loop through each one of those seeing if there's a `program_name` inside of it, etc, which should *eventually* lead me to the result.

Basically I'm creating large chunks of code for each individual possibility. Is there a smarter way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you could benefit from having an installer that writes to the registry. Then you'll know where all the files and folders are, even if the user installs to a weird location.

Comment: The original program isn't of my design, that's the core of the issue. But yes that's certainly how I'd do it.

Comment: Ah. I sympathize. Doing a recursive search is probably your only choice, then. Optionally: as a last resort, have the user indicate where it's installed.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what Charlie said -- you could wrap the original app in some kind of unified installer type thing that would write the registry and extract the app to whatever place the user decides. The installer would prompt the user for the location to install to, and would extract to that location. InnoSetup can be configured to write the uninstall info, put uninstall links, etc. You can customize the uninstaller part of the InnoSetup script to do whatever cleanup you need, and/or call other external programs, if necessary.

InnoSetup allows you to package stuff in the actual installer exe, so you only have to distribute one flle. I can verify that this works -- although I've never tried it for packing huge files.

Here's a link to InnoSetup: http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php